# Optimisation of LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, optimization, query-optimization, contains

Is there a way to optimise the following LINQ query? It is not efficient when arrays are big.

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
public static Test[] GetObjects(Test[] t, int[] ids)
{
    return t.Where(q => ids.Contains(q.Id)).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Are you _actually_ experiencing performance problems or are you just speculating? I don't think you can do any better than O(n^2) for this task.You can try storing `Test`s in a dictionary, using their IDs as keys, I guess...

Comment: Does `ids` have to be an array? If you could change `ids` to be a `HashSet<int>`, for example, it would be far more efficient. Note: I would *not* recommend doing something like `var hash = new HashSet<int>(ids);` *inside* the method - it should be done once *outside* the method, and the same hash reused in the same places that the array would have been used. Or, as @Sweeper notes: a `Dictionary<int, Test>` keyed by id - again reused, not calculated each time

Comment: When you do ToArray(), you're actually having a interaction with all elements on the list even you don't need yet. You can use IEnumerable<Test> and the query will happen when you really need.

Answer (score 2):

Don't return an array. Use `IEnumerable<Test>`. That will help greatly with memory use, especially if you can propagate that change further throughout your program's API surface. Any place you really do need an array, it's easy enough to call `.ToArray()` *after* the function call, but again... the less you do that, the more likely you are to save an array allocation and copy.

```
public static IEnumerable<Test> GetObjects(IEnumerable<Test> t, IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    return t.Where(q => ids.Contains(q.Id));
}
```

You might further improve things by converting the `ids` variable to a `HashSet<int>`. Whether this helps depends on the size of the collection:

```
public static IEnumerable<Test> GetObjects(IEnumerable<Test> t, IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    var idHash = new HashSet<int>(ids);
    return t.Where(q => idHash.Contains(q.Id));
}
```

or even better, so you potentially re-use the hashset or build the `ids` collection as a hashset in the first place:

```
public static IEnumerable<Test> GetObjects(IEnumerable<Test> t, HashSet<int> ids)
{
    return t.Where(q => idHash.Contains(q.Id));
}
```

In the database world I know you also could optimize this by first sorting the `ids` collection, but I'm not sure what that looks like right now for .Net and linq to be able to take advantage of an IOrderedEnumerable.

Comment: And as always for performance optimization questions, if this helps I'm curious to see before and after numbers.